# Images in full width and fade in when fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fade

I am trying to create a script using JQUERY that changes background images every 5 seconds. The problem is, I can't get the images to be full screen. Other problem I am having is that one image fades out, so that other image can fade in but there is a white space between the two of them. Is there any way to start the fade in at the same time as the fade out?

```js
$(window).load(function() {           
  var i = 0; 
  var images = ['geral2.jpg','geral3.jpg','geral4.jpg','geral5.jpg','geral6.jpg'];
  var image = $('#slideit');
  image.css('background', 'url(geral1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed');
  setInterval(function(){           
    image.fadeOut(1000, function () {
      image.css('background', 'url(' + images [i++] +') no-repeat center center fixed');
      image.fadeIn(1000);
    });
    if(i == images.length)
      i = 0;
  }, 5000);
});
```

http://codepen.io/Ryuh/pen/dXYzoM

Comment: Use two separate images, one in front of the other, and fade the last image out while fading the next image in.

Comment: The images change using the script above. I don't think I can do that.

Comment: That does the same but he has the background-color set for black instead of white

Comment: Just wanted to add if you wanted to have the fade occur simultaneously, simply take the second fadeIn outside of the callback of the FadeOut.

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you show and example in a pen please?

Answer (score -1):

See this resource: https://vegas.jaysalvat.com/ It's a background slider that stretches fullscreen (whether it's width or length) and has exactly the fade effect you're looking for.

Access all settings you're looking to change/alter here: http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/settings/

Easy to setup and looks great when it is. All code available to be downloaded.

Code will look as simple as:

```
$elmt.vegas({
    slides: [
        { src: '/img/slide1.jpg' },
        { src: '/img/slide2.jpg' },
        { src: '/img/slide3.jpg' }
    ],
    transition: 'fade'
});
```

Just in case any links above rot, you can always fork/download from github at this link: https://github.com/jaysalvat/vegas/

Comment: It's preferable not to have your answers as link only. Links rot and will render your answer invalid.

Comment: I'll edit and include more details.